# How to create transition matrix with groupby in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a `pyspark` dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
so = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c'],
                   'time': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   'group':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                   'value':['S','C','C','C', 'S','C','H', 'H', 'S','C','C','C']})

df_so = spark.createDataFrame(so)
df_so.show()

+---+----+-----+-----+
| id|time|group|value|
+---+----+-----+-----+
|  a|   1|    A|    S|
|  a|   2|    A|    C|
|  a|   3|    A|    C|
|  a|   4|    A|    C|
|  b|   1|    A|    S|
|  b|   2|    A|    C|
|  b|   3|    A|    H|
|  b|   4|    A|    H|
|  c|   1|    B|    S|
|  c|   2|    B|    C|
|  c|   3|    B|    C|
|  c|   4|    B|    C|
+---+----+-----+-----+
```

I would like to create the "transition matrix" of `value` by `group`

The transition matrix indicates what is the probability of e.g. going from `value` `S` to `value C` **within** each `id` while `time` progresses.

Example:

For `group A`:

- We have in total `6` movements
- `S->C` goes 1 time for `id==a` and 1 time for `id==b`, so `S to C` is `(1+1)/6`
- `C->S` is 0, since **within** `id` there is no transition from `C` to `S`
- `C->C` is `2/6`
- `C->H` is `1/6`
- `H->H` is `1/6`

Respectively we can do the same for `group B`

Is there a way to do this in pyspark ?

Comment: How do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @Emma Ideally, for each `group` a matrix where rows & columns would be the `value`s, and the elements of the matrix would be the probabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I use `lag` to make the source column (left side of transition) of the transition for each row, then count the frequency group by `source` & `value`(target) divided by the total count.

```py
lagw = Window.partitionBy(['group', 'id']).orderBy('time')
frqw = Window.partitionBy(['group', 'source', 'value'])
ttlw = Window.partitionBy('group')

df = (df.withColumn('source', F.lag('value').over(lagw))
  .withColumn('transition_p', F.count('source').over(frqw) / F.count('source').over(ttlw)))

df.show()

# +---+----+-----+-----+------+------------+
# | id|time|group|value|source|transition_p|
# +---+----+-----+-----+------+------------+
# |  c|   1|    B|    S|  null|         0.0|
# |  c|   3|    B|    C|     C| 0.666666666|
# |  c|   4|    B|    C|     C| 0.666666666|
# |  c|   2|    B|    C|     S| 0.333333333|
# |  b|   1|    A|    S|  null|         0.0|
# .....
```

If I understand what you like at the end,

```py
(df.filter(df.group == 'A')
 .groupby('source')
 .pivot('value')
 .agg(F.first('transition_p'))
).show()

# +------+---------+---------+---------+
# |source|        C|        H|        S| 
# +------+---------+---------+---------+
# |  null|     null|     null|      0.0|
# |     C|0.3333333|0.1666666|     null|
# |     S|0.3333333|     null|     null|
# |     H|     null|0.1666666|     null|
# +------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of transition matrix T poses that all rows of T should sum to one, which is different from your calculation.

To calculate the transition matrix (as in the definition of wikipedia), first calculate the frequency table. The code should be run after selecting the group subset.

1. Count the number of transitions from A to B

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                   'time': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                   'page':['S','C','C','C', 'S','C','H', 'H']})
win1 = Window.partitionBy(["id"]).orderBy("time")
df = df.withColumn("page_next", F.lead("page",1).over(win1))
df = df.where(F.col("page_next").isNotNull())
```

2. Find all node permutations and then join the empirical data

```
nodes = df.select("page").drop_duplicates()
paths = nodes.crossJoin(nodes).toDF("page", "page_next")
data = df.groupby("page", "page_next").agg(F.count(F.col("id")).alias("cnts"))
path_cnts = paths.join(data, on=["page", "page_next"], how="left").fillna(0)
freq_matrix = path_cnts.groupby("page").pivot("page_next").agg(F.first("cnts"))
```

This should return the frequency matrix where each cell contains numbers of transitions observed from row node A to column node B.

3. Normalize each row to sum to 1.

```
node_names = freq_matrix.columns[1:]
row_sum = sum([freq_matrix[node] for node in node_names])
trans_matrix = freq_matrix.select("page", *((freq_matrix[node] / row_sum).alias(node) for node in node_names))
```

If you want the transition matrix as per your definition.
Simply divide each cell by `data.count()`.

This does not utilize groupby enough, so seems slower.